# OutputStream hasSpaceAvailable never becomes 'true'

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, external-accessory

On an iPhone, with ios 6.1.3, I'm trying to write to an outputStream, without an NSRunLoop. My stream is simply initialized by:

```
    session = [[EASession alloc] initWithAccessory:accessory
                                       forProtocol:protocolString];
    if (session)
    {
        NSLog(@"opening the streams for this accessory");
        [[session inputStream] open];
        [[session outputStream] open];
        [session retain];
        streamReady = true;
        receivedAccPkt = true;
    }
```

Then, elsewhere in the code, when I try to transmit data as follows:

```
uint8_t requestData[8] = {0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5, 0x6, 0x7, 0x8};
while (![[eas outputStream] hasSpaceAvailable]);
@synchronized(self) {
    len += [[eas outputStream] write:requestData maxLength:8];
}
```

The 'hasSpaceAvailable' method never returns true, so the code is stuck.

Are there any other initialisation tasks to be done for an output stream, in order to send data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EASession documentation states that you need to configure the streams by assigning it a  delegate which handles the stream events and schedule it in a run loop.

Using a run loop enables you to drive the streams without worrying about threads. For example, if you write into the output stream via the `outputStream` property, there's very likely an *internal* input stream (bound to the public visible output stream) which is used by the `EASession` object to obtain the bytes written. This *internal* input stream (which is not visible) may also use the same run loop as the publicly provided output stream `outputStream`.

Don't mismatch the internal input stream with the public input stream! So basically, there are two public streams and two internal streams. Each public stream has an associated pendant internally: a input stream has a bound output stream, and an output stream has a bound input stream.

You *can* however, avoid using a run loop for your (output) stream: you just need to guarantee that the `write:maxLength:` method is executed on a *private* thread, which is not used by the internal streams by `EASession`.

You can *get* your private thread just by utilizing dispatch. You may try the code below:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
    [outputStream open];
    const char* data = ...;
    int dataLength = ...;
    while (dataLength && !isCancelled) {
        int written = [outputStream write:(const uint8_t*)data maxLength:1];
        if (written > 0) {
             dataLength -= written;
             data += written;
        }
        else if (written < 0 )
        {
            // error occurred
            break;
        }
    }
    [outputStream close];
});
```

Note: this will block the thread if a previous call to `write:maxLength:` returned zero and if there is still data to write. Thus, the internal streams must not use the same thread, otherwise you get a dead lock.

When the thread is blocked, it becomes difficult to cancel the block. Perhaps, you should try a run loop approach.

Comment: Working with runloops in the context of streams is "recommended", not a "requirement", is that correct? (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/PollingVersusRunloop.html). I understand it is "better" to use runloops, but I should still be able to use polling mode, I think. The reason why I switched from runloops to polling is explained (I hope) in another question that I posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19768512/blocking-communication-with-ios-accessory

Comment: You may try the "blocking approach". My code snippet shows how to accomplish this.

Comment: Is there a way to do what I am trying to do with NSRunLoop, or is it just impossible? That is, write a function that looks like " (NSMutableArray*) sendAndReceiveData:(NSMutableArray*)txData ", which will send data to the device, wait for its response, and return the data using runloops?

Comment: The run loop approach employs asynchronous programming style. If you try to wrap an asynchronous pattern into a synchronous method, you suffer from some kind of "impedance mismatch". Effectively, this means, that you need to *block* the outer synchronous method until after the asynchronous internal method is finished. While this is possible, it's not a recommended practice - or more precisely it's a "code smell". A better wrapper around a run loop approach would be an asynchronous method with a completion handler. Does this sound more appealing?